# Formatting dictionaries with Equal values Json Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, function, dictionary, format

I am trying to modify `data` dict so that only the names within the `dictionary` which are  `RSI, MOM` is remained within the `data` dict. How could I create a function that filters and looks for equivalent names in both dicts `data` and `dictionary` then delete everything else?

Code:

```
dictionary= {'Account1': {'RSI': OrderedDict([('Exchange', 'Bybit'), ('AccountName', 'Account1'), ('StrategyName', 'RSI'), ('Script', 'MomentumStrats'), ('StratStatus', 'ACTIVE')]),'MOM': OrderedDict([('Exchange', 'Bybit'), ('AccountName', 'Account1'), ('StrategyName', 'MOM'), ('Script', 'MomentumStrats'), ('StratStatus', 'ACTIVE')])}, 'Account2': {}}

def reading(): 
    with open('data.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data
reading()
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "RSI": [
      {
        "TradingPair": "BTCUSD",
        "fetchSubscriptions": [0],
      }
    ],
    "MOM":[
        {
            "TradingPair": "BCHUSDT",
            "fetchSubscriptions": [0],
        }
    ]
}
```

JSON File:

```
{
    "RSI": [
      {
        "TradingPair": "BTCUSD",
        "fetchSubscriptions": [0],
      }
    ],
    "MOM":[
        {
            "TradingPair": "BCHUSDT",
            "fetchSubscriptions": [0],
        }
    ],
    "MOM_RSI":[
        {
            "TradingPair": "BTCUSDT",
            "fetchSubscriptions": [0],
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create a `set` for the unique values that are in the `dictionary` and then iterate over `data` and delete any keys not in the unique set. So,

```py
set_unique = set()

for v in dictionary.values():
    for k in v.keys():
        set_unique.add(k)

print(set_unique)  # Output: {'MOM', 'RSI'}

for key in list(data.keys()):
    if key not in set_unique:
        del data[key]

print(data)   # Output: {'RSI': [{'TradingPair': 'BTCUSD', 'fetchSubscriptions': '[0]'}], 'MOM': [{'TradingPair': 'BCHUSDT', 'fetchSubscriptions': '[0]'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the relevant names from `dictionary` by using the `keys()` method. Make this a set so we can quickly check the contents.

```py
required_names = set(dictionary["Account1"].keys())
```

Or for under any account:

```py
required_names = {key for account in dictionary for key in dictionary[account]}
```

Then you can use a dict-comprehension to filter for only those keys. Something like:

```py
filtered_data = {
    key: value
    for key, value in data.items()
    if key in required_keys
}
```